# Expand OS X partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, core-storage

I am using a Mac (OS X 10.10.3) that has a Windows and an OS X partition. From Windows, I shrunk the Windows partition using `diskmgmt.msc` freeing up about 60 GB. I would like to expand the OS X partition into this free space. Disk Utility seems have greyed out the size field of the partition.

[image]

Here is the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`:

```
start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640   96408680      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   96818320    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   98087856       1104
   98088960  226988032      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  325076992  165157727
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

How do I expand it?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` to your question!

Comment: Unfortunately, (to the best of my knowledge - correct me if I am wrong) there is no way to do this without deleting the partition and recreating it. I had to do this yesterday because I had the same problem. If anyone has a workaround, let me know!

Comment: @klanomath did so

Answer (score 2):

The recommended method to expand Macintosh HD is to backup and remove your Windows partition with [WinClone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone), expanding your OS X volume and restoring the Windows partition. This can also be done with `dd` and `fdisk`. Both methods require an external drive.

---

A **very** non-conventional method exists to expand Macintosh HD by using the internal Logical Volume Manager (CoreStorage).

Your main volume is already part of a CS Logical Volume Group – probably because it's encrypted. This can be seen by checking the partition type of disk0s2: 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC.

After adding a partition in the unallocated disk space, formatting it as JFHS+ volume and adding it as physical volume, you may expand the logical volume *Macintosh HD* into the free space of the now enlarged logical volume group.

**The method outlined below was tested in a VM and it works. Since I can't install Windows with the Boot Camp Assistant in a VM I can't assure that Windows is bootable afterwards. If Windows booting fails you can use `fdisk` to modify the pMBR to make it bootable again.**

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite). If you boot to a full system you have to prepend `sudo` using some commands (e.g. `gpt` or `newfs_hfs`)

Verify and repair the disk and the volumes with *Disk Utility*

**Modify CoreStorage stack:**

- Open in the menubar Utilities/Terminal

  First you should get an overview of your disks and the partition layout:
- Enter `diskutil list`, `diskutil cs list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`
- Unmount the disk containing the logical volume Macintosh HD and you main disk. Below I assume the logical volume (residing in disk0s2) has the disk identifier disk2 – check your diskutil listing for the proper identifier and use that one below.

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk2
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  ```
- Add a partition in the unallocated disk space:

  ```
  gpt add -b 325078016 -i 5 -s 165156696 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- Format the new partition:

  ```
  newfs_hfs -v "Expansion" -J /dev/rdisk0s5
  ```
- Add the partition to the logical volume group. The lvgUUID (the UUID of the Logcal Volume Group) can be found in the `diskutil cs` listing:

  ```
  diskutil cs addDisk lvgUUID /dev/disk0s5
  ```
- Expand the logical volume. The lvUUID (the UUID of the Logcal Volume) can be found in the `diskutil cs` listing:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID 0g
  ```

  0g is a magical number here and it will expand the LV to the max size.
- Verify and repair the disk and the volumes with *Disk Utility*

  The partition map finally looks like this:

  ```
  start       size  index  contents
            0          1         PMBR
            1          1         Pri GPT header
            2         32         Pri GPT table
           34          6
           40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640   96408680      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     96818320    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     98087856       1104
     98088960  226988032      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
    325076992       1024  
    325078016  165156696      5  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECA
    490234712          7
    490234719         32         Sec GPT table
    490234751          1         Sec GPT header
  ```

  Your *Macintosh HD* will now span disk0s2 and disk0s5 (similar to a Fusion disk but with one disk only).